# will my PSU handle an external graphics card?

Tags: power-supply

i have a 300 watts PSU,and i'm considering buying an ATI HD4670,will my PSU handle that card properly?

I have an AMD Phenom II X3 720 and a gigabyte GA-MA790GP-UD4H mobo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For future reference on the topic:

http://educations.newegg.com/tool/psucalc/index.html

A handy PSU calculator courtesy of newegg.com

Comment: And two (better) others: http://web.aanet.com.au/~SnooP/psucalc.php http://extreme.outervision.com/psucalculatorlite.jsp

Answer (score 6):

in a word: no.

[**ATI Radeon™ HD 4600 Series System Requirements**:](http://ati.amd.com/products/Radeonhd4600/requirements.html)

> 400 Watt or greater power supply (550
>   Watt for ATI CrossFireX™ technology in
>   dual mode) is recommended

Answer (score 1):

It probably will not handle any current video card.  That's not to say that maybe you couldn't find an older card that would work with your psu, perhaps an older pci.  I doubt it will have the performance you are looking for though.  Power supplies are fairly inexpensive so upgrading it usually doesn't kill your wallet and it's a good place to plan for the future also.  The more steady power you have the better.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly better to have a slightly overrated power supply rather than an underrated one, as the latter could result in an blown PSU or even damaged components.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what most others say, I'd say this will work fine. I have a 4670 with a 300 watt PSU [I'm pretty sure that's what it is anyway :p] and it works fine. The 4670 doesn't need a PCIE power connector, it uses solely what it gets from the PCIE port.

Comment: and what about performance?

can you provide benchmarks for your machine?

Answer (score 0):

4670 is rated for only 59 watts max. It's a very efficient card.